# How to change and add the GDPR consentform.html file for iOS

Tags: html, ios, swift, admob

I'm using `AdMob` in my app and I want to change the title of the text on the last button in google's gdpr consent form that says `Pay for the ad-free version`.

[image]

On [google's gdpr docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/eu-consent#forward_consent_to_the_google_mobile_ads_sdk) it says:

> To update consent text of the Google-rendered consent form, modify the
>   consentform.html file included in the Consent SDK as required.

To access it I went line `864` inside the `consentform.html` inside the blue `Pods` icon inside the `PersonalizedAdConsent` folder inside the `Resources` folder.

[image]

Even after I changed the line to say `Access the limited ad-free version` after I launched the app it still said `Pay for the ad-free version`.

[image]

**How can I modify it?**

Comment: Have you deleted the derived data and rebuild?

Comment: I’ll try it and get back to you, thanks

Comment: @Kerberos hey post that as an answer and I'll accept it, it worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `New Build System` the pods libraries are builded only once.

So if you need changes inside the pod library or when you are creating a new pod library don't forget to clean the build folder (⌘+⇧+k) after each change.

Comment: what's the New Build System?

Comment: New build system is a new type of build written and optimised for Swift. 
Xcode new build system is available in Xcode 9+, like default build system from Xcode 10. 
Look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes/build_system_release_notes_for_xcode_10) for all the details.